# Python 2.7 - How to call individual columns from transposed csv file

Tags: python-2.7

I understand that the csv module exists, however for my current project we are not allowed to use the module to call csv files.

My code is as follows;

```
table = []
for line in open("data.csv"):
 data = line.split(",")
 table.append(data)
 transposed = [[table[j][i] for j in range(len(table))] for i in range(len(table[0]))]
rows = transposed[1][1:]
rows = [float(i) for i in rows]
```

I'm really new to python so this is probably a massively basic question, I've been scouring the internet all day and struggle to find a solution. All I need to do is to be able to call data from any individual column so I can analyse it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your data is organized in a list of lists. Each sub list represents a row. To better illustrate this I would avoid using list comprehensions because they are more difficult to read. Additionally I would avoid using variables like 'i' and 'j' and instead use more descriptive names like row or column. Here is a simple example of how I would accomplish this

```
def read_csv():
    table = []
    with open("data.csv") as fileobj:
        for line in fileobj.readlines():
            data = line.strip().split(',')
            table.append(data)
    return table

def get_column_data(data, column_index):
    column_data = []
    for row in data:
        cell_data = row[column_index]
        column_data.append(cell_data)
    return column_data


data = read_csv()
get_column_data(data, column_index=2) #example usage
```